# mod_rewrite generator not rewriting URLs

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have this url: `http://localhost/design/oferta.php?tip=Restaurant&nume=Test&localitate=Calnic%20&judet=Alba&id=5206337cd1cef` and I want it to look like this: `http://localhost/design/oferta/Restaurant-Test-Calnic%20-Alba-5206337cd1cef.php`.
I tried using the following code inside .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^design/oferta/([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.php$ /design/oferta.php?tip=$1&nume=$2&localitate=$3&judet=$4&id=$5 [L,R]
```

It doesn't rewrite my URL. I got this code generated by the generator that I found at http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/. Is there anything that I am missing? Also... will this work for all of my URLs or just for the one I pointed? I want it to work for all of the dynamic "oferta?..." URLs. When I try to access the second url (the one that I want) it shows me a 404 error page. The .htaccess is created as it should. I know this question is not really general but I guess I'm not the only one that used this little generator. Please let me know so that I can edit my question before downrating. Thanks!

I just edited my initial question to reflect some changes that I made since I asked. Please take your time and read the question again. Long story short: I regenerated the URL code that I want but with a different desired URL. It now generates a 404 page.

Comment: What URL are you entering in your browser to test this rule?

Comment: When I entered: `http://localhost/Restaurant-Test-Calnic%20-Alba-5206337cd1cef.php` it did redirect to `http://localhost/design/oferta.php?tip=Restaurant&nume=Test&localitate=Calnic%20&judet=Alba&id=5206337cd1cef` **internally**. If you want URL to change in browser then add `R` flag as `[L,R]`

Comment: I just edited my question. After that I added The R flag and now it generates a 500 error page instead of the 404.

Comment: Tell me what is the error in Apache error log file.

Comment: I have no experience with servers whatsoever but this is the last line in my error log. [Sat Aug 31 06:45:18.048244 2013] [core:alert] [pid 3940:tid 1464] [client ::1:50285] C:/xampp/htdocs/Design/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters
I guess that's what you wanted to see?

Comment: Solved the 500 error. I had a space between L, and R. Now I'm back to the 404 error page.

Comment: Good sign. Now tell me what URL are you seeing in your browser when you had `R` flag in the rule.

Comment: localhost/design/oferta/Restaurant-Test-Calnic%20-Alba-5206337cd1cef.php

Comment: That is your original URI. After redirect you should be getting something like: `/design/oferta.php?tip= Restaurant...`

Comment: No, I'm not getting anything. The URL stays the same, the only thing that changes is that I'm not seeing http:// but if I copy paste the URL it's still there so I guess that Google Chrome just hides it.

Comment: I have tested it and it seems to be working fine redirecting to `http://localhost/design/oferta.php?tip=Restaurant&nume=Test&localitate=Calnic%20&judet=Alba&id=5206337cd1cef`. Make sure you have .htaccess and mod_rewrite is enabled and working.

Comment: I checked with phpinfo() if it's enabled or not and it's enabled. As for .htaccess I'll tell you exactly what I did. I created a file with no extension set and named it .htaccess. I also made a copy of this file in the includes folder of my project. Could that be the problem?

Comment: I uploaded the .htaccess on a server that I use for showcase. You can check the page here: http://www.showcase.zz.mu/oferta.php?tip=Club&nume=Goblin&localitate=Bucuresti&judet=Bucuresti&id=52138700c4d7c

Comment: Something isn't riht: `http://www.showcase.zz.mu/design/oferta/Restaurant-Test-Calnic%20-Alba-5206337cd1cef.php` becomes: `http://www.showcase.zz.mu/?`

Comment: Is there any way I can send you a private message with the authentification data for the host?

Comment: E-mail sent. You can switch the hosting's language to english or whatever suits you better.

Comment: Alright I will attend it after finishing some work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^oferta/([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.php$ /oferta.php?tip=$1&nume=$2&localitate=$3&judet=$4&id=$5 [L,R,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you Anubhava! This worked like charm. If you have the time please take a look at this question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18540346/adapting-links-after-mod-rewrite . They are kinda linked but I thought it would be better for others to separate them.

Comment: You're welcome. I will read that question and try my best to answer there.