# adapting links after mod_rewrite

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

With the help of someone from Stack Overflow I managed to change my links so that they are more user and search engine friendly. This URL `http://www.showcase.zz.mu/oferta.php?tip=Club&nume=Goblin&localitate=Bucuresti&judet=Bucuresti&id=52138700c4d7c` got changed to this URL `http://showcase.zz.mu/oferta/Club-Goblin-Bucuresti-Bucuresti-52138700c4d7c.php`. If I try to access the new URL manually it works as it should. However on my search page the generated link is still the old one and the URL stays the same when accessing the dynamic generated page.

This is my .htacess content:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^oferta/([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.php$ /oferta.php?tip=$1&nume=$2&localitate=$3&judet=$4&id=$5 [NC,L,QSA]
```

This is the code that generates the links in PHP:

```
echo "<a href='oferta.php?tip={$result['tip_locatie']}&nume={$result['denumire_locatie']}&localitate={$result['localitate']}&judet={$result['judet']}&id={$result['id_oferta']}'><p style='margin-top: -5px;'>View page</p></a>";
```

In case you're wondering what $result is:

```
$result = mysql_fetch_array( $resulta )
$resulta = mysql_query($query)
```

If there's anything more that you need to see let me know. Also let me know before downrating so that I can edit my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an additional rule for external redirect from old URL to new URL. Have your code like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+oferta\.php\?tip=([^&]*)&nume=([^&]*)&localitate=([^&]*)&judet=([^&]*)&id=([^\s&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /oferta/%1-%2-%3-%4-%5.php? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^oferta/([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.php$ /oferta.php?tip=$1&nume=$2&localitate=$3&judet=$4&id=$5 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: That worked, I tought it would be something that involved tweaking my PHP code, didn't expected it to be that simple. Do you know any good sources where I could learn these things? And I'm not talking only about mod_rewrite but rather the whole .htaccess thingy. What can I do with it and how. Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out. In my opinion Google Search on Stackoverflow answers is probably the best source for these things.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try!